# How to setup SES SMTP in WHM cPanel shared hosting

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, amazon-ses, whm, amazon-lightsail

I am using WordPress for my websites and I hosted it in AWS lightsail with cPanel WHM. However, The SMTP of the website added in cPanel is not working. I am using a plugin called Easy SMTP.

I tried to test the email but it's says 'Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to serverSMTP server error: Failed to connect to server SMTP code: 111 Additional SMTP info: Connection refused', even though my credentials are correct and SES are verified. By the way I manage the DNS records in Cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking your cPanel Firewall?

Please try navigate to
Plugins > ConfigServer Security & Firewall > Firewall Configuration

And Look for **SMTP_Block**, also try to check if it was enabled and if it was enabled make sure to disabled.